# Boost linking error for boost filesystem, why?

Tags: gcc, boost

I have built boost 1.44 on CentOS 5.5 using the gcc that is part of CentOS 5.5. All targets built fine. However trying to build a simple cpp file with nothing but an include of boost filesystem results in this linking error (3 times):

undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'

I cannot see why this would happen. The lib is build, it can be seen, and yet I've seen this error discussed in google searches for versions of boost going back quite a while (when built with gcc). Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `-lboost_system` to your `LDFLAGS` when linking your simple app.

Comment: how do i add the `-lboost_system`? what is the command to type?

Comment: @alvas: On Linux, type this in the terminal: `g++ your_file_name.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem`